# How to passing value from Iterator into paintComponent

Tags: java, graphics, iterator, binary-tree, paintcomponent

My goal is to make a method that prints a binary tree.

`T_tree` is an `Iterator` that returns an object with both the `x` and `y` coordinates and also the key variable.

I am trying to find a way to send those values from the `Iterator` to the `paintComponent` method.

The problem seems to be that the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method has been initialized before the `T_tree` iterator.

How can I solve this? This is my code:

```
public class print_tree extends JPanel {

    Iterator T_tree;    

    print_tree(tree _tree) {
        T_tree = _tree.iterator();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        while (T_tree.hasNext()) {
            node_cor temp = (node_cor)T_tree.next();

            g.drawOval(temp.x_cor, temp.y_cor, 30, 30);
            g.drawString(""+temp.key+"",temp.x_cor ,50+temp.y_cor);
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: No. There's no way a method of an object runs before the constructing this object has been executed. The problem, though, is that paintComponent() is called **every time** the component must be repainted. But an Iterator can be iterated only once. You need to store an Iterable (i.e. a collection), not an Iterator.

Comment: I made the changes 
print_tree(tree _tree){ 

T_tree = _tree.iterable();
this.repaint();
>}

I think that it  supposed to do the fallowing 
\\
1. call to pintComponent 
2. set T_tree 
3. call again to pintComponent this time with initialized T_tree

Comment: it is not solve the problem, what i get is Jframe with white screen, i need to find a way to call to the paintComponent again ,after i initial the Iterator, it sims that "this.repaint()" dose not do the recall. i am Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class print_tree extends JPanel {

tree_Iterator T_tree; // this is not an iterator  
                       //i switch from using stack to dynamic array     

public  print_tree(tree _tree){

    T_tree =(tree_Iterator) _tree.iterator();
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{ 
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    darray _arr = T_tree.arr;
    for(int i=0;i<=_arr.end;i++)
    {
        node_cor temp = _arr.arr[i];

        g.drawOval(temp.x_cor, temp.y_cor, 30, 30);
        g.drawString(""+temp.key+"",temp.x_cor ,50+temp.y_cor);

    }

}
```